# Trouble deploying a Rails app (Linode, Passenger)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, passenger, linode

I'm a brand new Rails user, I'm following this tutorial- http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/a-demo-app#top .  Had no issues accessing the demo app (from Chapter 2) on the local server.  However having issues deploying to my Linode server.  Here's what I've done:

1. Push the local app to BitBucket
2. Clone the repo on Linode to: /srv/www/preziki/first_app
3. Bundle install
4. rake db:migrate
5. Update VirtualHost for preziki:

   ServerAdmin oleg@preziki.com
   ServerName preziki.com
   ServerAlias www.preziki.com
   DocumentRoot /srv/www/preziki/first_app/public
   ErrorLog /srv/www/preziki/logs/error.log
   CustomLog /srv/www/preziki/logs/access.log combined
6. a2ensite preziki
7. Restart apache
8. Reload apache

If I go to www.preziki.com (or 176.58.104.181), I see the default Rails "Welcome aboard" page.  If you click the "About your application environment" link, you get the "Sorry but something went wrong" error.  If I go to www.preziki.com/users, (like I could with localhost/users), I get teh "Sorry but something went wrong" error.

If I point VirtualHost to the dir where I have a "Hello world!" index.html file, then preziki.com displays it without a problem.

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: Update- I reinstalled libapache2-mod-passenger, now when I click "About your application environment" I'm getting a "The requested URL /rails/info/properties was not found on this server." error.

Comment: Update- Here are the last few entries for the /srv/www/preziki/logs/error.log file:

[Thu Jul 12 04:45:56 2012] [error] [client 67.168.204.53] File does not exist: /srv/www/preziki/first_app/public/assets, referer: http://www.preziki.com/
[Thu Jul 12 04:45:59 2012] [error] [client 67.168.204.53] File does not exist: /srv/www/preziki/first_app/public/rails, referer: http://www.preziki.com/
[Thu Jul 12 04:46:04 2012] [error] [client 67.168.204.53] File does not exist: /srv/www/preziki/first_app/public/rails, referer: http://www.preziki.com/

Answer (score 1):

First thing you can see the "default Rails" environment,  means check your web server(apache) is working fine. because its a static request.

Second things when you want to go into application environment, then their is a problem means your application is not deploy properly.

Few thing you need to check.

```
1. Give the application directory all permission.
2. bundle install properly
3. Set RailsENV in virtual host
4. rake db:migrate properly.
5. Check your log file what problem it is showing.



<VirtualHost *:80>
      ServerName localhost
      DocumentRoot /home/user/project/trunk/public
      PassengerEnabled on
      RailsEnv development
      <Directory /home/user/project/trunk/public>
      </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're nearly there. My guess is that the app has a problem connecting to the database. But to see for yourself what the problem is, look in the production log file:

```
/srv/www/preziki/first_app/log/production.log
```

That will usually tell you everything you need to know. Another thing you can do to debug is to use the console on the server, in production mode:

```
bundle exec rails console production
```

Comment: my /first_app/log dir is empty.  bundle exec rails console production throws the following error: "/home/[username]/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb/completion.rb:9:in `require': cannot load such file -- readline (LoadError)"